# C++ ostream and ofstream conversions

Tags: c++, ofstream

My code has an `ostream` object that is accumulated by various modules and ultimately displayed to the console. I'd like ALSO to write this `ostream`object to a file, but do I have to rewrite all of that code using an `ofstream` object instead, or is there a way to convert one to the other (perhaps via a `stringstream`?)

For example, many of my existing functions look like

```
ostream& ClassObject::output(ostream& os) const
{
    os << "Details";
    return os;
}
```

Can I call this function with an `ofstream` object as the argument and have that `ofstream` object accumulate information instead?

Comment: *"Can I call this function with an ofstream object?"*  Yes. `ofstream` inherits from `ostream`, so you can pass the `ofstream` directly to that function.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can. That's the point in the OO concept called [subtype polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29#Subtype_polymorphism_.28or_inclusion_polymorphism.29). Since `ofstream` derives from `ostream`, every instance of `ofstream` is at the same time an instance of `ostream` too (conceptually). So you can use it wherever an instance of `ostream` is expected.

Answer (score 0):

**ofstream derived from ostream so**

Just add some code in **main.cpp**

```
#include "ClassObject"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     ClassObject ob;
     cout << ob; // print info to console window

     // save info to .txt file
     ofstream fileout;
     fileout.open("filename.txt", ios::app);
     fileout << ob;
     fileout.close();

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hope, it's useful!